# JSON string containing escaped single quote flagged as invalid

Tags: javascript, json, vbscript

JSONLint says the following is invalid JSON:

```
[{
"value": 71,
"label": "123 Foobar \'eha-Kauai, Hawaii, United States"
},
{
"value": 75,
"label": "456 Foobar \'elima-Kauai, Hawaii, United States"
}]
```

Yet this works:

```
var foo = [{
"value": 71,
"label": "123 Foobar \'eha-Kauai, Hawaii, United States"
},
{
"value": 75,
"label": "456 Foobar \'elima-Kauai, Hawaii, United States"
}];
console.log(foo.length); // returns 2
```

---

Note: the string is generated by a function which could be used in the following ways:

```javascript
<script>
var foo = '<%= vbs_JSONEncode("Hello World") %>'; // being inconsistent
var bar = "<%= vbs_JSONEncode(str_Hello_Msg) %>"; // with the quotes
</script>
```

Or simply:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
Response.Write vbs_JSONEncode("Hello World")
```

Comment: JSON is not JavaScript. Invalid JSON is not automatically invalid JavaScript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to escape a `'` with a backslash. Just escape the `"`.

Comment: Correct, You are already "inside double quotes, therefore you must escape \" these and not ' these"

Comment: Why does the unnecessary escaping make the JSON invalid? The problem here is that my function is generic; on some places its wrapped inside `'` and on other times it is `"` (see my edit).

Comment: If you define a string using `'...'` the list of valid escape-sequences (`\n\t\r`...) is extended by `\'` (vice-versa for `"..."`). In `"\'"` `\'` is an invalid escape-sequence while in `'\"'` `\"` is an invalid escape-sequence.

Comment: @Marcel: Strings cannot be defined with `'` in JSON anyway.

Comment: @Salman: Have a look at the syntax of JSON strings: http://json.org/ `\'` is not a valid character sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the escaping of the single-quote marks, which is unnecessary in JSON, since only double quotes are used.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the backslashes?

Found with http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the ' to be escaped since double quotes are used. That needs to be removed and the JSON becomes valid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like JSONLint just doesn't care too much for `\` inside your JSON. Wether or not it is an invalid character for JSON, i don't know.. But as @dogbane says, no need to escape `'` unless you use that char for your string encapsulation..

Comment: Of course it cares, that's why it is not valid. The syntax definition can be found here: http://json.org/